# GA - Creating a report of pages visited by the hour of the day?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to create a custom report that will have a table like so:

```
page name     visit time
page1         15:30:15
page2         15:31:12
page1         15:30:45
```

and so on.

Is it possible to create such a report in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

The highest level of precision available by default is the minute available with the `ga:dateHourMinute` dimension:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/?#ga:dateHourMinute

**If you need more precision than minutes, you have to implement a custom dimension** (eg to record seconds or milliseconds).

**Here is an example** for implementing such hit timestamp with millisecond precision using GTM:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/13-useful-custom-dimensions-for-google-analytics/#11-hit-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a **custom dimension** (called in this case 'visit time') at **hit level** that contains the **timestamp** of the hit when it is sent to Analytics.